# Removing listview from form and adding it to another form, slow

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need help on speeding up a listview remove and add from one form to another.
I have a list view that generally contains about 11000+ items every time. So I am constructing it separately. When I need to use any form, I add this already constructed one. Everything works fine, except when re-adding it to another form and closing the instances when application ends. It takes about  10~15 seconds just to re-add or close the app. But initial add is fine and quick. even the removal. I am not disposing the form that I am removing it as well. Also I put timers in code to see, which line is taking. Strangely, no code execution is taking time, but after that code block completes, application hangs sometime before coming up for use.

```
    public void LoadControls()
    {
        someObject.LoadView(ref lvw1,); //
        this.lvw1.Visible = false;
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.lvw1, 0, 1);
        this.lvw1.Visible = true;

    }
    public void UnloadControls()
    {
        this.lvw1.Visible = false;
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        this.lvw1.Visible = true;
        lvw1 = null;
    }
```

Comment: showing some code would help, show how are you adding, removing and re-adding your items to the list views

Comment: Its not items, its the entire listview itself getting transffered from one form to another.

Comment: You did not show how you are moving the view from one form to the next.

Comment: The Form is same, just that it has many instances. So, Call Unload from the exiting one and call load from the entering one

Comment: `I need help on speeding up a listview` - You might want to see [this short clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA)